# Save excel worksheet as PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

When saving Excel worksheets, I used to get the option to save it as PDF.
Now working on a new computer, when I want to save a worksheet as PDF, I have a limited number of file extentions I can use. Amongst them no PDF.
Question: how can I add the PDF option to this list

Comment: As it stands, there is not much that can be said. Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1404439/edit) to give us more info, what version of Excel? Windows? are they different? anything else is different about teh two machines? etc...

Answer (score 1):

A) Install Adobe Acrobat Pro.   [Adobe.com](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat.html)

-or-

B) Find a "pdf printer" program and print to a pdf.  A number of versions of these programs are out there.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 and MacOS X include Print to PDF in the default list.  For instance, in MacOS, hit Ctrl-P, click the PDF pulldown on the bottom, and choose 'Save as PDF' .  In Windows 10, hit Ctrl-P, choose 'Microsoft Print to PDF' from the list, and when you Print, it will prompt for where to Save.

The free Adobe Acrobat Reader also includes a PDF printer driver.  You can also install standalone PDF printer drivers like CutePDF, PDFCreator, or FoxIt.

I've never used the Export to PDF function in Excel, preferring Print to PDF.